# Passing arguments to Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, arguments

I have a list item

```
<ul><li id='1'>Testing</li></ul>
```

I want to pass the id of this element (1) to a jquery snippet. For example:

```
$('#homepage li').qtip({
  content: {
  url: 'testsite.php?id=!!!THIS IS WHERE THE ID SHOULD BE PASSED!!!',
  method: 'get'
  },
  show: 'mouseover',
  hide: 'mouseout',
  })
```

Any ideas?

Comment: note that id=1 is not w3c valid. you cant start ID's with numbers

Comment: @meo - it's not valid in HTML4, that's a clear distinction that should be made now, given the adoption/use of HTML5 by many.

Comment: ye that was just as an example, plan to stick a letter in front to make it valid. cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) here so you can reference the element as you're setting it up, like this:

```
$('#homepage li').each(function() {
  $(this).qtip({
    content: {
      url: 'testsite.php?id=' + this.id,
      method: 'get'
    },
    show: 'mouseover',
    hide: 'mouseout'
  });
});
```

Note that your numeric only IDs are only valid in HTML4 (though they're just fine in HTML5).